# upgrading to sublime text 3 3126 build, it stopped showing "install package" option

Tags: sublimetext3

I recently upgraded to sublime text 3 3126 build. After this update, latest udpate stopped showing "install package" option. I could not find answer to this other than ignoring couple of packages which sublime 3 doesnt like. I am waiting for another build to come to fix this problem.

Comment: Check the list of ignored packages to see if PackageControl is listed in it. There was some sort of bug in the latest version where for some people the upgrade gets stuck part way.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -4):

Add following to ignore list -

Preferencecs -> Settings

```
"ignored_packages":
[
    "ApplySyntax",
    "BracketHighlighter",
    "Color Highlighter",
    "DictionaryAutoComplete",
    "SublimeCodeIntel",
    "Vintage",
    "WordHighlight"
],
```

https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/1168

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue you linked to. There is absolutely **no reason whatsoever** to put just these packages in the ignored list. The issue you linked isn't even completely filed yet, let alone addressed and resolved. Just picking random packages from someone's incomplete bug report won't fix anything.